# Is it possible to set the desired DPI of an image created using raspistill?

Tags: camera

I realize that the amount of information taken by raspistill is the same regardless of the DPI  of the output, but nonetheless - is it possible to set this on the command line? If not, what utility would provide such functionality ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ExifTool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) avoids reencoding the image:

```
exiftool -jfif:Xresolution=300 -jfif:Yresolution=300 *.jpg
```

It should be in the repo.

Comment: cool - this seems ideal, especially since the Pi is relatively short on computation power.

Comment: I think this technically only sets the JFIF resolution tag on JPEGs. this may not be respected by all software

Answer (score 1):

You could install Imagemagick

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

And then you could do

```
convert -units PixelsPerInch input.png -density 300 output.png
```